# 2008 R2 - SSIS Script Component Output - Variable Column Length

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2008, script-component

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, BIDS, to create a SSIS package.

I'm trying to use a variable to define the length for one of my script component outputs in my data flow.

[image]

Obviously this doesn't work. I'm wondering if there is a workaround so I don't have to hard code that length.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't put variables there. Normally you will know the length for the columns (from business, database schema, etc). Otherwise, put a big enough safe size.